# Link a RibbonSplitButton button click with its menu opening in an XML ribbon

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2017, ribbon-control

I'm using a XML ribbon for an Excel add-in with C#. I'm new at this so I hope I have not misunderstood how it works.
I have a SplitButton containing a button and a menu. I'd like the menu to open up when clicking the button just like if I clicked the caret.

What I have in XML:

```
<splitButton id="_mySplitButton" size="large">
      <button id="_mySplitButton__btn" onAction="ShowMenu"/>
      <menu id="_mySplitButton__mnu">
            <!-- buttons here -->  
      </menu>
</splitButton>
```

What I have in C#:

```
public void ShowMenu(IRibbonControl control)
{
    // Open the dropdown here
    RibbonButton button = control as RibbonButton; // --> null
}
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to get to the menu dropdown. I cannot cast the callback parameter, nor can I access the control programmatically, as I've seen on several posts.
So I'm wondering, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution: using menus instead of splitbuttons.
The menu's / splitbutton's appearance is the same, but a menu will open itself upon hovering or clicking, which is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the [gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/017f9f94-700f-4846-ba19-c695ad32929f):

```xml
<gallery id="alignGallery"
    label="Align"
    imageMso="ObjectsAlignLeft"
    size="large"
    showItemLabel="true"
    columns="1"
    onAction="OnGalleryButtonClicked"
>
    <item id="alignLeft" label="Align Left" imageMso="ObjectsAlignLeft"/>
    <item id="alignCenter" label="Align Center" imageMso="ObjectsAlignCenter"/>
    <item id="alignRight" label="Align Right" imageMso="ObjectsAlignRight"/>
</gallery>
```

```csharp
public void OnGalleryButtonClicked(IRibbonControl control, string id, int index)
{
    switch(id)
    {
        case "alignLeft":
            MessageBox.Show("Align Left selected.");
            break;
        case "alignCenter":
            MessageBox.Show("Align Center selected.");
            break;
        case "alignRight":
            MessageBox.Show("Align Right selected.");
            break;
    }
}
```